# The exclusion tag can't solve the duplicated dependency version

Tags: maven

Here is my problem, I have a `parent pom.xml` which defines the:

```
--------parent pom.xml-----------------
<dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
    <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Inside this `roboletric pom.xml` we have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ant-tasks</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Inside the `maven-ant-tasks pom.xml`, it has:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So whenever I am calling the API which only exists in the maven-artifact 3.0.3 in the roboletric test case, it will throw `nosuchmethod` exception.

So I have tried:

```
1. <dependency>
       <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
       <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

1. I also tried moving:

   org.apache.maven
       maven-artifact
       3.0.3

to the child pom under the `<dependencyManagement>` which I think it should override the parent but actually it didn't.

I think this kind of problem should be very common but I just can't figure it out, any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with Ant Task calling yourself ? Furthermore `org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3` does not contain a dependency on maven-artifact So your execlusion is useless. robolectic in contradiction has a dependency to maven-ant-task so you should execlud `maven-ant-task` instead and define the dependency `maven-ant-task` directly in your pom and there you can exclude the `maven-artifact` dependency from it.

Comment: Since we are adding the test cases implemented using the roboletric and integrated the test case execution during the maven build and that is the reason we added the robolectric in the parent pom.

Comment: to extend the comment above, the parent pom is not directly depending on the maven-ant-tasks but the roboletric since we are adding the roboletric test cases in our maven project and we have no idea and interest to know what this roboletric is depending on(if everything works). I have tried to exclude the maven-ant-tasks from the parent pom but then we have to manually add quite a few other dependencies defined in the maven-ant-tasks because they are needed to run the roboletric test cases and I think this is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should define dependency management in your parent POM to nail down the version of `maven-artifact` in all (transitive) dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks, I double checked the parent pom and the <dependencyManagement> was there, sorry for not mentioning it, updated the question.